# I'm stuck with Next Auth authorize part. Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next-router

For the past couple of weeks I'm unable to solve the following error in next.js with authorization. I'm stuck at the NextAuth signIn part. Below are the images for my auth.js file inside lib directory,

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/github"

export const { 
    handlers: {GET, POST}, 
    auth, 
    signIn, 
    signOut, 
} = NextAuth({ 
    providers: [ 
        GitHub({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID, 
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }) ,
    ],
});
```

Below is the code for `action.js`.

```
"use server"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { Post } from "./models";
import { connectToDb } from "./utils";
import { signIn, signOut } from "./auth";

export const addPost = async (formData) => {
    // const title = formData.get("title");
    // const desc = formData.get("desc");
    // const slug = formData.get("slug");

    const {title, desc, slug, userId} = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    try{
        connectToDb();
        const newPost = new Post({
            title,
            desc,
            slug,
            userId,
        });

        await newPost.save();
        console.log("saved to db")
        revalidatePath("/blog")
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        return {error: "Something went wrong!"}
    }
}

export const deletePost = async (formData) => {

    const {id} = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    try{
        connectToDb();
        await Post.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        console.log("deleted from db")
        revalidatePath("/blog")
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        return {error: "Something went wrong!"}
    }
}

export const handleGithubLogin = async () => {
    "use server";
    await signIn("github");
}

export const handleLogout = async () => {
    "use server";
    await signOut();
}
```

Inside `app/(auth)/login/page.jsx`, I've the following code which is not working and giving me error at `await signIn("github")` part in `action.js`.

```
import { handleGithubLogin } from "@/lib/action";

const LoginPage = async () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form action={handleGithubLogin}>
        <button>Login with Github</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage
```

Inside `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js` I've the following code

```
export { GET, POST } from "@/lib/auth";
```

Please, help me solve this api routing problem with nextauth, I've tried the documentation but nothing helped.